# How to do I install gddrescue and ddrescuegui on Ubuntu Mate 18.04.2?

Tags: mate

I've installed Ubuntu Mate 18.04.2 to its own 40GB partition on an 80GB HDD.
The computer is online, and I've updated Ubuntu with all offered updates.

I want to run `ddrescue` to copy files from an ailing drive to a new one. 
Both drives are the same size. Both will be slaved into the system.

I know how to open the Terminal but I'm not sure what commands to use to install `ddrescue` and its GUI. The actual copying, I think I can handle.

Answer (score 3):

[GNU DDrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) (command line tool), since it available on [default repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gddrescue&searchon=names) — you only need:

```
sudo apt install gddrescue
```

The `ddrescue-gui` which is GUI frontend for original GNU DDrescue is available [from PPA](https://launchpad.net/~hamishmb/+archive/ubuntu/myppa?field.series_filter=bionic):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hamishmb/myppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ddrescue-gui
```

Comment: `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/hamishmb/myppa/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.` It doesn't work for me, what should I do?

Comment: @Unknown123 Meaning the PPA doesn't support your distribution, from what I look it seems your Linux OS is not Ubuntu ? Try execute `lsb_release -a` in terminal.

Comment: `No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:        2020.2
Codename:       kali-rolling` Yes It is not. I couldn't find the ppa for kali. What should I do next?